# Change iOS tab view from alert

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a tabbed application with 2 tab views.  I want to change the view from the second tab to the first when the user presses "OK" on an alert view.

The following code snippet works when I use it on an -IBAction button pressed, but it doesn't do anything when I use it inside the alert code:

self.tabBarController.selectedViewController = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

Why does it not work when used as below, in my SeondViewController.m in my

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];?

UIAlertView *alert =[[UIAlertView alloc]
initWithTitle:@"Camera and Target coincident"
message:msg
delegate:nil
cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
self.tabBarController.selectedViewController = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
```

I'm just learning this, so anything you can offer would be helpful.

When I use the following code:
  if ([ theProjection Trans_Initialise] == 1) {
       NSString * msg = nil;
       UIAlertView *alertView =[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Camera and Target coincident" message:msg delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
       [alertView show];

```
   - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
       if ([[alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex] isEqualToString:@"OK"]) {
           self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
       }
   }
```

I get the error message on -(void) alertView  "Invalid argument type void to unary expression"  Am I doing something grammatical, or is it (quite possibly) something I just didn't understand?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need a delegate call back from the alert view informing you about the button that was clicked.

Your alert view should be created like this :

```
UIAlertView *alert =[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Camera and Target coincident" message:msg delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

Then in your m file implement the function :

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if ([[alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex] isEqualToString:@"OK"]) {
        self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: Correct but I wouldn't check the button title. It would be better to do: ```if (buttonIndex == 0)``` or whatever index the confirm button it. That way if you change the text of the button you don't also have to change this code to prevent an error.

Comment: @kmcgrady the button title is what I use at times to differentiate between multiple alert views in my code ... But yeah you are right too ...

Comment: Using the button title is a very bad idea. If you localize your alerts for other languages, it won't work. If you go back and change the button titles for some other reason, it won't work. As a coding rule, don't write your code to depend on display content. Alert views use consistent button indexes for the different responses. Use the index.

Comment: @MohitAthwani Use the ```.tag``` property to differentiate between alert views. When you create an alert view give it a tag (any number) and then in the delegate you check ```if (alertView.tag == 1)``` and then check the button index within that conditional.